# using break and else conditional statements with for loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How to break for loop in list comprehension based on condition and use else block after it?

here is code that I want to convert in list comprehension:

```
x=int(input("Enter a number : "))

for i in range(2,x+1):
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i%j==0:
            break
    else:
        print(i)

#this program prints all prime numbers upto x.
```

**My Attempt :**

```
x=int(input())

def end_loop():
    raise StopIteration
    
prime=list(i for i in range(2,x+1) for j in range(2,i) end_loop() if i%j==0 )

print(prime)
```

**Output :**

```
SyntaxError
```

**Required Output :**

```
All prime numbers upto x
```

I prefer :

⏺️One liner

⏺️Pure python

Comment: What does ```end_loop()``` do in the ```list``` type call? :)

Comment: A syntactically valid expression would be `list(i if i%j!=0 else end_loop() for i in range(2,x+1) for j in range(2,i))` but this doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to think about what condition the `for` loop is checking for, and then think about different ways of expressing it.  In this case, the loop is testing to see if the `i` value is divisible by `any` of the `j` values:

```
print([
    i for i in range(2, int(input("Enter a number : ")) + 1)
    if not any(i % j == 0 for j in range(2, i))
])
```

Note that instead of `not any(i % j == 0 ...` you could just say `all(i % j ...`!

Comment: Thank you so much sir it worked..! I was asking is their any way to use break in list comprehension? no problem if not just wanna know...

Comment: I think the not any can't be directly replaced by ```all(i % j ...```, for instance, ```all(3 % 2...``` resulted in a ```False``` and hence won't be counted as a prime number. Instead, another ```if``` required as in ```all(False for j in range(2, i) if i % j == 0)```.

Comment: No such thing as a `break` in a comprehension, no.  Not all loops can necessarily be converted into a comprehension statement.

Comment: @HenryTjhia I assure you it works fine -- `all(X for X in Y)` is in general equivalent to `not any(not X for X in Y)`.  :)  When I made the change in my version of the script it did indeed return 3 as a prime.